# задать класс всем элементам, кроме последнего?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как задать класс `subtitle` всем элементам массива кроме последнего?

```
  renderText=(text, index) => (
       <p
           className={classNames({
              ts: true,
              subtitle: ????
           })}
         key={text}
     >

    </p>
);

text.map(this.renderText);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  renderText=(text, index) => (
   <p
       className={classNames({
          ts: true,
          subtitle: if(++index !== this.length) text
       })}
     key={text}
 >
</p>
);
text.map(this.renderText, text);
```

Второй аргумент к `map` [привязывает](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) оператор `this` к `text`, что позволяет получить размер массива (начиная с 0-го элемента) с помощью `this.length`.
Альтернативно можно использовать `bind(text)`.

Comment: @werty, отметьте ответ как правильный, если он решает вашу проблему

Comment: написала, как сказали, но parsing error линтер ругается, так писать нельзя условие. на if ругается

Comment: renderText = (textrow, index, text) => (
              <p
                  className={classNames({
                   ts: true,: true,
                   subtitle: index !== text.length - 1
            })}

             key={text}
        >
          
        </p>
    );

Comment: с text поулчилось. this не видит